# Group by day, sum up same product numbers, then group by week and sum up products by product number, then group by week and sum up all products

Tags: pandas, date, group-by

I have a dataframe df like:

```
date       | productnumber | kpi
2018-04-02 | 1             | 0.3
2018-04-02 | 1             | 0.7
2018-04-02 | 1             | 0.5
2018-04-02 | 2             | 0.1
2018-04-02 | 2             | 0.1
2018-04-02 | 2             | 0.8
2018-04-02 | 3             | 0.1
2018-04-02 | 3             | 0.2
2018-04-02 | 4             | 1.8
2018-04-06 | 1             | 3.2
2018-04-06 | 2             | 0.1
2018-04-06 | 2             | 0.2
2018-04-06 | 4             | 0.4
```

First I need to group by the same date and productnumber to sum up the kpi for all the same products for the same day.

That should be possible with:

```
df = df.groupby(["date", "productnumber "]).sum()

date       | productnumber | kpi
2018-04-02 | 1             | 1.5
2018-04-02 | 2             | 1.0
2018-04-02 | 3             | 0.3
2018-04-02 | 4             | 1.8
2018-04-06 | 1             | 3.2
2018-04-06 | 2             | 0.3
2018-04-06 | 4             | 0.4
```

Then I need to sum up all products by productnumber and week

End result should be this:

```
date       | productnumber | kpi
2018-04-02 | 1             | 4.7
2018-04-02 | 2             | 1.3
2018-04-02 | 3             | 0.3
2018-04-02 | 4             | 2.2
```

Then I need to throw away all kpis < 1 and sum up all products by week, resulting in:

```
date       | kpi
2018-04-02 | 8.2
```

If my date is 2018-31-12 and this day is a monday week of the year would be 1 so just creating a column with week_of_year and grouping by that does not work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: product 4. why after second `group` expected `kpi` = 0.4 but not 2.2(1.8 + 0.4)?

Comment: `2018-04-01/2018-04-07` period is actual for dates: 2018-04-01, 2018-04-06

Comment: Sorry, you're correct of course. Edited second "group by" (how do you make the background grey in comments?).

Comment: [here](https://prnt.sc/ucv2sw) example

Answer (score 1):

Because if use `Grouper` here are shown next weeks values one possible solution is subract `7 days` before your solution and use `closed='left'` in [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] -= pd.Timedelta('7D')

df = df.groupby(["date", "productnumber"]).sum()
print (df)
                          kpi
date       productnumber     
2018-03-26 1              1.5
           2              1.0
           3              0.3
           4              1.8
2018-03-30 1              3.2
           2              0.3
           4              0.4

df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W-Mon', level="date", closed='left'), 
                            "productnumber"]).sum()
print (df)
                          kpi
date       productnumber     
2018-04-02 1              4.7
           2              1.3
           3              0.3
           4              2.2
```

Last filter and for aggregation sum by first level is possible use this shortcut:

```
df = df.query('kpi > 1').sum(level=0)
print (df)
            kpi
date           
2018-04-02  8.2
```